# How open gpio in embedded linux?

Tags: embedded-linux

According to the gpio documentation of openwrt, I entered the following command in the console:

`echo "26" > /sys/class/gpio/export`

The console prompts " write error: Device or resource busy".
This gpio is a led pin. How should I drive this gpio?

Answer (score 1):

GPIOs already defined in the device tree cannot be exported. Fortunately, LEDs can be controlled in another file:

```
echo "100" > /sys/class/leds/<device>:<color>:<func>/brightness
sleep 1
echo "0" > /sys/class/leds/<device>:<color>:<func>/brightness
```

LED will flash.